# How can I set CherryPy's application access_log level before it starts?

Tags: logging, cherrypy

I am trying to suppress both global and application layer access_log output by setting the loglevel to 30 before quickstart but this only seems to work for the global logger. I can set the loglevel of the application logger after it starts but I want to set its loglevel before it starts. Anyone know how to achieve this ?

For the global access_log this works prior to starting cherrypy:

```
cherrypy.log.access_log.setLevel(30)
```

However, the app_id is not known until cherrypy starts so I am passing the following config before it start, but it is not honored and the application layer access_log still has loglevel 20 (INFO)

```
self._srv_thread = Thread(
    target=cherrypy.quickstart, 
    kwargs={
        'root' : self.Root(self, 
                           self._authenticator, 
                           self._authorizer),
        'script_name' : '',
        'config' : {'/': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'request.show_tracebacks': False,
            'tools.trailing_slash.on': False,
            'tools.response_headers.on': True,
            **'log.access_log.loglevel' : 30,  #  <-- not honored !!!!!**
            },},
        }, 
    daemon=True)
self._srv_thread.start()
```

Log output:

```
2020-06-04 23:28:47,189 rpi1 cherrypy.access.1978553616[5651] INFO 192.168.178.187 - - [04/Jun/2020:23:28:47] "GET /master/loggers HTTP/1.1" 200 1205 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
```

After it starts I can make the following call to change the application layer access_log's loglevel successfully:

```
cherrypy.tree.apps[''].log.access_log.setLevel(30)
```

How can I set both loglevels before cherrypy starts the application ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `'log.access_log.on': False`?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a workaround by setting the loglevel after cherrypy starts. This didn't work at first either for the application access logger - it seems the application loggers are created some time after the application is mounted/started so I added a thread which checks every second if the application has started and then sets the log level to the desired level. Here is the class method code in case anyone is interested. The method can be called for each logger (access and error logger) with parameter 'logger_name' set to string "access_log" or "error_log":

```
def set_cp_loglevel(self, logger_name, value):

    def set_cp_app_ll_run():
        sleep(1)
        set_cp_app_loglevel()

    def set_cp_app_loglevel():
        if cherrypy.tree.apps:
            l_app = getattr(cherrypy.tree.apps[''].log, logger_name)
            l_app.setLevel(value)
            debug_log(self, msg + "done.")
        else:
            debug_log(self, f"waiting for cherrypy to start...")
            t = Thread(target=set_cp_app_ll_run, daemon=True)
            t.start()

    msg = debug_log(self, f"setting {logger_name} loglevel to {value}...")
    if not (isinstance(value, int) and value in (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)):
        raise ValueError(f"loglevel must be one of these: "
                         f"{(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)}, got {value}")
    l = getattr(cherrypy.log, logger_name)
    l.setLevel(value)
    set_cp_app_loglevel()
```

I am still hopeful to hear how to do this properly before cherrypy starts.